# How to Embed Google Search

Tags: javascript, html, web

I have always wondered how to embed Google on a webpage. Is it possible to put it in an `iframe`? I know that some websites use Google CSE, but I want the *real* Google. If so, how can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can embed [this URL](https://www.google.com/webhp?igu=1&gws_rd=ssl) (aka `https://www.google.com/webhp?igu=1&gws_rd=ssl`) in an `iframe` without fail. The `?igu=1` is what makes it work. I found this answer from [agoogleaday.com](http://www.agoogleaday.com), which uses an `iframe` to house an experimental Google search website.

```html
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/webhp?igu=1&gws_rd=ssl" width="640" height="480" frameborder="0">Your browser does not support <code>iframe</code>s. Please consider using a <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">modern</a> browser.</iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the google logo and just the search box, you can use this:

```html
<form target="_self" id="google" method="get" action="http://www.google.com/search" target="main" onsubmit="window.top.close();">
    <input name="q" id="google" placeholder="Google Search" size="40" maxlength="2000" value="" type="text" autofocus></input>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check this-
https://support.google.com/customsearch/answer/2630969?hl=en