# want to show external link page on popup in React

Tags: reactjs, iframe

> I'm trying to show google page on my popup, but it is giving me msg in iframe 'www.google.com refused to connect'

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Popup from './components/Popup';

class App extends ReactComponent{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = { showPopup:false};
    }

    togglePopup(){
        this.setState({
            showPopup:!this.state.showPopup
            });
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
            <h1> Simple Popup Example InReact Applicaion </h1>
            <button onClick={this.togglePopup.bind(this)}> Click To Launch Popup </button>

            {this.state.showPopup?
                <Popup
                    text='Click "Close Button" to hide popup'
                    closePopup={this.togglePopup.bind(this)}
                />
            : null
            }
            </div>
        };
    }
}

export default App;
```

Popup.js

```
import React from 'react';
import  './style.css';

class Popup extends React.Component{

    render(){
        const google = "<iframe width='100%' height='100%' scrolling='no' src='http://www.google.com' sandbox='allow-modals allow-forms allow-popups allow-scripts allow-same-origin'></iframe>";

        return(
            <div className='popup'>
                <div className='popup_inner'>
                    <h1> {this.props.text} </h1>
                    <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: google ? google :""}}/>
                    <button onClick={this.props.closePopup}> close me </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Popup;
```

> My approach is not working. I can go with the other approach as well if that works. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you needed to replace `http` by `https` for security purpose.

With that done, one will get

```
Refused to display 'https://www.google.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.
```

It states that Google prevents us to use `https://www.google.com` directly in an iframe.

However, thanks to that [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33978037/how-to-embed-google-search/33979304), it is shown that you can bypass this limitation using an other url: https://www.google.com/webhp?igu=1&gws_rd=ssl ([working example here)](https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-lovelace-782jr)

Comment: Cool, it works. Thanks. What if I want to use other urls in place of "https://www.google.com/webhp?igu=1&gws_rd=ssl" . eg. https://www.facebook.com/ or any other url ? '/webhp?igu=1&gws_rd=ssl' not working with other urls, it is google.com specific, i guess.

Comment: This trick is specific to Google. You indeed need to find a specific URL that might work. But with Facebook, you have authentication as well so I guess it can get tricky